# How can I use ScrollView Tag

Tags: android

How do I use `ScrollView` tag . I just want a simple example of `ScrollView` to scroll a `TextView`.
 
**This is what I tried:**

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"   
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But I can't see the scroll bar on the emulator.

Comment: Ok then you need to enter large size of text, so when the text will be larger then the screen size it will automatically show you vertical scroll bars.

Comment: other then large size of text, more lines of text will also do it.

Comment: Change width and height of ScrollView to match_parent. Also set height and width of TextView to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you:

Buddy You don't need to use a ScrollView

**Set these properties in xml which contains TextView:**

```
android:maxLines = "6" // enter integer value
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

**And Put the below code in your Activity file which contains TextView Code:**

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Dude  Activity file means MainActivity.java

Comment: yes buddy, if you are writing code for `TextView` in `MainActivity.java`